# Puppeteer - How to get an array of elements of a first element?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I know that `$$eval` gets an array and `$eval` gets the first element that encounters.

But I have the following problem/question: how can I get an array from the first element that Puppeteer finds? **I need an array with the content of div of the first figure tag.**

```
<div>
   <figure class="test">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
   </figure>
   <p></p>
   <figure class="test">
      <div></div>
   </figure>
</div>
```

How can I tackle this?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you're asking, but can you not use `page.$$eval("figure.test div", els => els.map(e => e.textContent))`, because as you suggest, `$$eval` returns an array?

Comment: If my code above doesn't work, please provide the page itself as a [mcve]. There are many reasons why elements may not be selectable--you may need `waitForSelector`, or the elements might be in an iframe or shadow root, or the elements are out of the viewport, or the site is blocking you as a bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that should be super easy.

For accessing the *first child div*:

`const requiredEl = await page.$eval('figure', _figure => _figure.firstChild);`

For accessing all *children div*:

`const requiredEls = await page.$eval('figure', _figure => _figure.children);`

Comment: That didn't work. I need an array of those divs below the first figure.

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood your question. Updated the answer accordingly

Comment: [You can't return DOM nodes from `$eval`](https://blog.appsignal.com/2023/02/08/puppeteer-in-nodejs-common-mistakes-to-avoid.html#attempting-to-return-objects-and-dom-elements-from-evaluate-callbacks).